# "Do you want my peanuts?"

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember this one scene from a movie, and would really like to be able to refer to it in a piece about humor. Can you identify the movie?

The character barely makes it in time to board an airplane and is a bit fazed by the effort. It turns out he is sitting next to a Frenchman who wants to strike a conversation. This becomes a bit awkward for both and they fall silent.

Then the Frenchman tries a new approach. He asks something that sounds like "Do you want my penis?" and the main character is befuddled. The Frenchman insists and the situation becomes more tense, until he puts the hand in his pocket, pulls a packet of airplane peanuts and repeats (heavy accent) "Do you want my penis?" The main character acts relieved, says "Ah! 'Do you want my PEANUTS!' " snatches the bag and begins to chew nervously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this YouTube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2Os1QiglVQ) it's most probably from [*Speed Zone!*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098369/) the infamous maybe/maybe not third part of the *Cannonball* series.

Comment: Wow! Three hours to get the answer. I wondered for years :) Thanks.

Comment: @yrodro Want to know how I found it? I typed *"do you want my peanuts"* into *google* and the *YouTube* clip was the first result. But I also had a strong feeling that I knew it from one of the *Cannonball* movies myself.

Comment: Did search a while back... shoulda searched again :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds exactly like a joke from Jim Carrey in [Ace Ventura: when nature calls](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112281/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3), but this is with the stewardess:

> Airplane Stewardess: Peanut? [sounds like penis] Ace: Yes, I have one
>   right here. It's bulky, but I consider it carry-on. Airplane
>   Stewardess: Peanut.

Also see [this clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6OUYNxlYcM).

Comment: LOOOL glad to find out that someone else other than me thought about the same clip :))))))